# Binary data and image converting to string

Tags: python

I have key ,value pair(key="photo" and value="image.png") in terms of binary. I want to convert to dict

```
imag_bytes=b'{"photo": matrix data}'
```

How can I convert into dict for accessing matrix data

Data=photo["photo"] What's to matrix data.

Suggest me.

Comment: You are aware that you question is not really intelligible, aren't you? It is not just the English part. Not just what should be code: there is no way one can meaningfully help you with what you've posted here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ask someone around you to formulate your question in English.

Comment: again, do not use json, do not use base64. send the file itself, in binary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515981/poco-client-sending-image-using-c

Comment: this should never have been tagged as `OpenCV`. it's a plain python question.

Comment: yes after getting data i want to show using imshow using opencv

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the image to a base64 string. This is a common way of sending binary data over text based protocols.

Comment: Yes, you're correct    In my case I send data as binary( key and val pair) and I want to aceess the value based on key.

Comment: **do not** use base64. that's an insane suggestion. image files can be sent as is, in binary, without base64, without json, without any shenanigans.

Comment: if you mind give some examples

Comment: `addPart` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968134/poco-how-to-upload-image-to-webser-using-poco-in-c

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks,           But that is sending one image but I want to send live stream data.

Comment: over a HTTP POST request? your question doesn't do any streaming. blowing data up by using json and base64 encodings doesn't cause live streaming either.